# Accessing arrays in an array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

Let's say I have an array of pointers in C. For instance:

`char** strings`

Each pointers in the array points to a string of a different length.
If I will do, for example: `strings + 2`, will I get to the third string, although the lengths may differ?

Comment: Yes, `strings + 2` is `&(strings[2])`. No, the lengths of the strings will not always differ.

Comment: `char** strings` is not an array of pointers, sry.

Comment: To be clear, `strings[2]` is a pointer to the first character of the third string.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you will (assuming that the array has been filled correctly). Imagine the double pointer situation as a table. You then have the following, where each string is at a completely different memory address. Please note that all addresses have been made up, and probably won't be real in any system.

```
strings[0] = 0x1000000
strings[1] = 0xF0;
...
strings[n] = 0x5607;

0x1000000 -> "Hello"
0xF0 -> "World"
```

Note here that none of the actual text is stored in the strings. The storage at those addresses will contain the actual text though.

For this reason, `strings + 2` will add two to the strings pointer, which will yield `strings[2]`, which will yield a memory address, which can then be used to access the string.

Answer (score 2):

`strings + 2` is the address of the 3rd element of the buffer pointed to by `string`. 
`*(strings + 2)` or `strings[2]` is the 3rd element which is again a pointer to a buffer of characters.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking to access third element through expression

```
strings[2];
```

but this will not be the case because look at the type of expression `string[2]`

```
Type is char *
```

As according to the standards

`A 'n' element array of type 't' will be decayed into pointer of type __t__.With the exception when expression is an operand to '&' operator and 'sizeof' operator.`

so strings[2] is equivalent to *(strings + 2) so it will print the contents of the `pointer to pointer` at third location,which is the contents of a `pointer` i.e an address.
But

```
strings+2;
```

whose type is `char **` will print the `3 rd location's address,i.e,address of the 3rd element of array of pointer, whose base address is stored in **string.`

But in your question you have not shown any assignment to the `char ** strings` and i am answering by assuming it to be initialised with particular array of pointers.
According to your question it is silly to do

```
*(strings + 2)
```

As it is not initialised.